# Script amigo invisible (secret´s Santa)

Tags: python

Estoy intentado crear un script para un programa gráfico de amigo invisible, en el que se van incluyendo los participantes en un Entry y después se establecen exclusiones, he conseguido que a nadie le toque regalarse a sí mismo, pero no consigo establecer exclusiones predefinidas entre participantes antes de realizar el sorteo, por ejemplo: *Parejas que no se pueden regalar entre sí*.

Este es mi código:

```
from random import choice

regaladores = ["pedro", "ana", "luis", "maria", "juan", 
"sonia","angel", "ines"]
regalados = ["ana", "pedro", "maria", "luis", "sonia", "juan", 
"ines", "angel"]
numero_reyes = len(regaladores)

def sorteo():
    for i in range(numero_reyes): 
           
        regalador=choice(regaladores)
        regalado=choice(regalados)

        if regalador == regalado:
            sorteo()
        
        else:     
            print(f"A {regalador} le ha tocado {regalado}")
            regaladores.remove(regalador)
            regalados.remove(regalado)
            
sorteo()
```

Comment: Normalmente no defines una función dentro de un ciclo. Al final terminas con más código que si no la hubieras hecho.

Comment: Defines un diccionario donde la clave es cada nombre, y el valor es un array de las exclusiones

Comment: El código que aportas puede entrar en un bucle infinito de recursividad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como las listas `regaladores` y `regalados` contienen los mismos elementos he definido una única lista que he llamado `participantes`.

Usaremos un diccionario para guardar qué restricciones tenemos.
Tendremos como llaves los nombres de los participantes en el juego y como valores [sets](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/stdtypes.html#set) de aquellas personas a las que no puede regalar.
Uso sets porque quiero que comprobar la pertenencia a este contenedor sea rápido.

Definamos este diccionario.
Asumo que los individuos contiguos en la lista son parejas que no se pueden regalar entre sí.
Para otro tipo de restricciones podemos definir los sets con otro criterio.
<sup>1</sup>

```py
def calcular_restricciones(regaladores) -> dict[str, set[str]]:
    restricciones = dict()
    for marido, mujer in zip(regaladores[0::2], regaladores[1::2]):
        restricciones[marido] = {marido, mujer}
        restricciones[mujer] = {marido, mujer}
    return restricciones


restricciones = calcular_restricciones(participantes)
```

Al definir de este modo el diccionario siempre puedo añadir más restricciones.
Por ejemplo si `pedro` y `luis` no se pudieran regalar mutuamente bastaría con hacer `restricciones['pedro'].add('luis')` y `restricciones['luis'].add('pedro')`.

El resultado del algoritmo lo voy a guardar en un diccionario.
Las llaves serán el nombre del regalador y los valores serán el nombre del regalado.
Definamos la función `sorteo`.
La haremos recursivamente.
El caso base es aquel en el que la lista de regaladores está vacía.
Eso significa que todo el mundo entrega regalo.

En caso contrario, tomamos un regalador e iteramos entre aquellas personas que no tienen ningún regalador y que además no están en sus restricciones.

```
def sorteo(regaladores: list[str], regalados: list[str], resultado: dict[str, str]):

    # Caso base, todos los participantes tienen a quién regalar
    if not regaladores:
        return True

    # Vamos a intentar asignar un regalado al primer regalador de la lista
    regalador = regaladores[0]
    # Lista con las personas que aún no tienen a quién regalar
    regaladores_restantes = regaladores[1:]

    # Añado aleatoriedad al iterar los posibles regalados
    shuffle(regalados)

    # Itero todas las personas que aún no tienen quien les regale
    for regalado in regalados:

        # Si 'regalado' no puede ser regalada por regalador, paso a la siguiente
        if regalado in restricciones[regalador]:
            continue

        # Lista con las personas que aún no tienen quien les regale
        regalados_restantes = [i for i in regalados if i != regalado]

        # Añado a la solución la asignación actual
        resultado[regalador] = regalado
        # Recursivamente llamo a la función para saber
        # si la asignación me da una situación resoluble
        if sorteo(regaladores_restantes, regalados_restantes, resultado):
            # La asignación es correcta, salgo de la función
            return True
        else:
            # La asignación no es correcta,
            # la elimino e intento asignarle otro regalado
            del resultado[regalador]

    # Ninguna de las personas que necesitan regalador
    # pueden ser regaladas por 'regalador':
    # la situación es irresoluble.
    return False
```

Este código tiene margen de optimización.
Pero creo que la versión actual es un buen equilibrio entre eficacia y claridad.

A la hora de llamar a la función es importante notar que [`shuffle`](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/random.html#random.shuffle) es un algoritmo in situ ([in-place](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-place_algorithm)).
Eso significa que el primer argumento y el segundo deben ser objetos distintos.
Si sólo tenemos una lista `participantes`, en el segundo caso habrá que pasarla como una copia:

```py
resultado: dict[str, str] = dict()
sorteo(participantes, participantes.copy(), resultado)
print(resultado)
```

---

<sup>1</sup> A partir de Python 3.12 ese mismo bucle se puede escribir usando [`itertools.batched`](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.batched).

Comment: Y qué pasa si hay una persona sin pareja?

Comment: @Benito-B Entonces su `set` de restricciones tendría un único elemento: ella misma.

Comment: Pues así a ojo, yo casi diría que en algún punto te va a dar error el código. Lo probaste pasándole un número impar de participantes??

Comment: @Benito-B La función `sorteo` funciona para un número impar de participantes. La función `calcular_restricciones` no tiene sentido usarla con una lista con una cantidad impar de participantes.